# Hyperlinks inside of a function

Tags: javascript, text, hyperlink

I want to put a link on "one" in the following code

Javascript

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="text set one";
```

I will have multiple of these functions with different text so I need to be able to pick out text and attach links (that will lead to pop-up windows).

EDIT: I need the click able one to have something like

```
`"MM_openBrWindow('index.html','New_Window','width=500,height=500')"`
```

Comment: You should have tried at least.

Comment: Wow dude, you changed the question? LOL

Comment: @RápliAndrás he just forgot something else to mention.

Comment: @user What do u mean by `click able one` do u just need the link to have an onclick event?

Comment: No, the original question was about a HYPERLINK. The new question is about a new function fired ONCLICK which should open a window with these dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this makes your job easier:

```
function myFunction () {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "text set " + "one".link("#");
}
```

Comment: Programmatically best answered.

Comment: [More information about `String.link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link). As explained, it should not be used in production code since it is not standardized.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction () {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "text set <a href='#'>one</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inlude `a` in innerHTML.

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="text set <a href='#'>one</a>";
}
```